# Python: How to sort a list by the max of each element?

Tags: python, list

```
L=[[a,b],[c,d],[e,f],...]
```

I want to sort it by max(a,b), max(c,d), max(e,f), etc.

Comment: The answer to "how do I sort a list by. . ." is always "use the `key` argument of the `sort` method".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can supply a custom `key` functor to `sort`:

```
L.sort(key=max)
```

Comment: You don't need to create a `lambda` function: `l.sort(key=max)` will work.